# Initialize transactional replication subscriber without initial snapshot

Tags: sql-server, replication

Is it possible to initialize a subscriber without an initial snapshot?

Replication is used in this case as an ETL tool to push data from processing servers to back end reporting data warehouse. Only inserts and updates are replicated, no deletes. The subscriber to-be already has all the tables, and some 1.5 TB of data in them. The publisher's tables have some 50Gb of data, most of it already on the future subscriber.

I want to start the subscription but I'm not interested at all in an initial snapshot, I just want it to start replicating new transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in SQL Server 2008 and above you can do that with initialize with LSN not sure if that can be done with SQL Server 2005.